# Object.assign breaks v-for (functional component)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am creating a Vue component ("Polar") to layout divs in a circular pattern. It does so setting the inline styles.

Now, I am having a weird issue when I use the component. It happens only under a very specific set of circumstances:

- I create multiple instances through `v-for`
- The Polar component is a "functional" component
- I pass the props as a referenced object (inline works fine!)
- The propsObject contains a nested StylesObject
- The custom Styles object gets merged as the first parameter of `ObjectAssign()`

What happens? All the instances in the v-for take on the value of the last item, like a closure was broken.

The code is a bit much to display here, so I have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/snirp/vue-polar) and [github](https://github.com/snirp/vue-polar). The first test shows the issue: all items are displayed on top of each other. The second test demonstrates that I can pass the exact same `propsObject`, only inline, and it works. Reversing the arguments in `Object.assign` also makes it work, as does converting the component to a normal/non-functional one.

I suspect this is some sort of Vue bug (or at least undocumented behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will change the first parameter (=target object). This caused my settingsObj to take on the other settings every time, until it had the settings of the last instance.

Easily resolved by changing

```
Object.assign(props.settingsObj, {setting: val, })
```

into

```
Object.assign({}, props.settingsObj, {setting: val, })
```

Sorry for blaming Vue, all my fault. Not exactly sure why this only happens with functional components, but it must be related to normal components being isolated in their own Vue instance.